# Drake Simulation compatibility with coRobots from Elephant Robotics; use Cobot in place of KUKA iiwa + wsg

Tags: drake, drake-r-package

Greetings. Wanted to check if the coBots Robotic arms from Elephant Robotics can be directly used in Drake simulator system? For example, in place of KUKA IIWA + WSG in https://manipulation.mit.edu/robot.html#example1 and the following examples, I want to use the cobot280 6-DoF Manipulator.
The following is the github link for the Cobots Arm containing URDF files:-
https://github.com/elephantrobotics/mycobot_ros2/tree/humble/mycobot_description/urdf/mycobot_pi
Can you advise if CoBot280 can be onboarded into Drake?
Please revert back.
Regards
Sandeep

Analysis of the URDF files to ensure that it works with Drake Simulation out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Drake ["Authoring Multibody Plant Tutorial"](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Drake-0b3b2c53-a7ad-441b-80f8-bf8350752305/project/Tutorials-2b4fc509-aef2-417d-a40d-6071dfed9199/notebook/authoring_multibody_simulation-9d9bd208c08a4e31a50e4c5d05234c4e).

It should be only a few lines for you to test this yourself.  E.g.

```
from pydrake.all import ModelVisualizer
v = ModelVisualizer()
v.AddModels(filename)
v.Run()
```

Comment: You have one primary obstacle: the geometry. The link you provided uses Collada (.dae) files for both visualization and geometry. Drake currently doesn't consume .dae files. For now, you'll want to convert them (obj or gltf for `<visualization>`, obj for `<collision>`). See https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__geometry__file__formats.html.

You might also consider replacing the mesh collision geometry with some bounding primitives. When Drake is given generic triangle mesh for contact, it replaces it with an bad convex hull.

Comment: Thanks Sean Curtis  for the response. I will convert the .dae files into .obj files using an online conversion tool and update the .urdf. In the meantime, can you elaborate on the second point, "......You might also consider replacing the mesh collision geometry with some bounding primitives. When Drake is given generic triangle mesh for contact, it replaces it with an bad convex hull....". What should I be doing here? Can you please provide me more instructions? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's safe to start from simply using the obj directly for the collision geometries, too.  But you can speed up your simulation by replacing it with simpler geometry (like the examples [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/119c7f4c18afb0444a64fa188d24bbc64cf78924/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/urdf)), or convex decomposition/mesh simplification tool like [create_sdf_from_mesh.py](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/037cd30da1bb844c1ce8aaa3e6dbc604037b9158/manipulation/create_sdf_from_mesh.py).